# Menu Program, Input string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create C++ menu program that does a lot of things such as count bytes, lines, words in a file.

I did all that. But what I could not do is to accept an mixed cases from the user. For example, if the user input `"countbytes"` the program will run but if he entered `"CouNt Bytes"` the program will not run.

So how could I do it?

Comment: C++ does not know about menus. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The question is not about menus, but about user input and string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to change the logic that you have already developed, an easy solution is to take the input from the user and convert it into lower case. Then process it.

Comment: Thanks, how did I did not think about it. Oh it is 4am now.

Comment: If this solved your problem accept it as an answer. Will save time for other users and will help me as well.